# OS X Lion Web Sharing can't start

Tags: macos, web-sharing

OS X Lion Web Sharing won't start. I checked it with apachectl configtest and got this:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 102 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: LoadModule takes two arguments, a module name and the name of a shared object file to load it from

How can I proceed?

Comment: also, when I try and test the psp with <?php phpinfo(); ?> I get [ Error writing info.php: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

Please check line 102 of the file `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`, perhaps the format of the `LoadModule` statement is wrong.

The right format is:

```
LoadModule info_module libexec/apache2/mod_info.so
```

Comment: just checked this. the format is and was correct

Comment: when I enter /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf I get an access denied statement